# Translate all english text on the page to arabic automaically onload

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I am translating a page automatically onload to arabic from english using the below code :

```
<!--This code will translate page contents automatically (without user input).
Settings located at line 9, current script will translate english to arabic-->
<style>#google_translate_element,.skiptranslate{display:none;}body{top:0!important;}</style>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script>
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'ar', autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
        var a = document.querySelector("#google_translate_element select");
        a.selectedIndex=1;
        a.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    }
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

But this code translates the page sometimes and sometimes it does not. I still can't figure out the exact reason behind this. Is there anyone who faced similar issue and knows about this behaviour ?

Comment: Add the `defer` attribute to your script so that the script is run *after* all the HTML is parsed and loaded

Comment: Thanks for your help brother. Should the defer attribute be used for both the scripts or only for the second script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @samanthigamajig comment I added `defer` and `async` to the below line which seems to be working for me

```
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" defer async></script>
```